# Unable to fetch private data from collection. Getting blank response

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am trying to explore private data collection and I have written the chaincode in javascript. I am passing the proper collections file while instantiating the chaincode and while invoking the chaincode I am adding the transient data in request payload which looks like this :

```
const proposal_request = {
  chaincodeId: chaincodeId,
  fcn: functionName,
  args: args,
  chainId: channelCode,
  txId: tx_id,
  transientMap : { "private" : "test data"}
};
```

My chaincode file looks like this :

```
const shim = require('fabric-shim');
const util = require('util');

var PrivateDataChaincode = class {

 // Initialize the chaincode
 async Init(stub) {
  console.log('<================> ::Private Data Chaincode Instantion:: <=================>');
  return shim.success();
 }

 async Invoke(stub) {
  console.log('<================> ::Private Data Chaincode Invocation:: <=================>');
  let ret = stub.getFunctionAndParameters();
  console.info(ret);
  let method = this[ret.fcn];
  console.info('methodName');
  console.info(method);

  if (!method) {
   console.error('No method of name:' + ret.fcn + ' found');
   return shim.error('No method of name:' + ret.fcn + ' found. \n UNKNOWN FUNCTION INVOCATION: ' + ret.fcn);
  }
  console.info('\nCalling method : ' + ret.fcn);
  try {
   let payload = await method(stub, ret.params);
   return shim.success(payload);
  } catch (err) {
   console.log(err);
   return shim.error(err);
  }
 }

 async createPrivateDataInCollection(stub, args) {
  if (args.length != 2) {
   throw new Error('Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 2');
  }

  // arg[0] has the collection name
  // arg[1] has the key

  console.info("============= START : Create Private data ===========");
  // get the transient map
  let transientData = stub.getTransient();
  await stub.putPrivateData(args[0], args[1], transientData.map.private.value);
  console.info('============= END : Create private data ===========');
 }

 async queryPrivateDataInCollection(stub, args) {
  console.info('============= START : Query private Data ===========');
  // arg[0] has the collection name
  // arg[1] has the key
  // query private data with argument
  let allResults = await stub.getPrivateData(args[0], args[1]);
  if (!allResults) {
   throw shim.error("Can't get data from state");
  }
  console.log(allResults);
  return allResults;
 }
};

shim.start(new PrivateDataChaincode());
```

I am storing data using the createPrivateDataInCollection method and fetching the data using queryPrivateDataInCollection. The private data is getting stored correctly when I cross checked in the couch DB. The problem I am facing is that I am getting a blank response when I am querying the private data using queryPrivateDataInCollection method on some occasions. Sometimes I am able to see the data, while sometimes I am getting a blank response. Am I missing something important?

Comment: Can you see what is your wait timeout for query transactions? Because you are saying, it returns sometimes, but fails in a while, so you can try increasing the wait timeout on the client side.

Comment: Hi Chintan, it actually doesn't look like a timeout error as I am getting a response, albeit an empty string. Still trying to figure out what's going wrong